# ¿Por qué no se añaden los puntos por etiqueta?

Tags: soporte, etiquetas, medallas-de-etiqueta

Ayer obtuve 210 puntos en mis respuestas y vi que no se me habían sumado los puntos de las correspondientes etiquetas. **No me refiero los +10 por upvote si no los puntos por etiqueta por upvote.**

Al principio pensé que era porque había superado el límite de los 200 puntos diarios pero pregunté en el chat y @Mariano (¡Gracias!) me respondió con este link: [Do you get credit towards your tag score after hitting your daily reputation limit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296187/do-you-get-credit-towards-your-tag-score-after-hitting-your-daily-reputation-lim) en el cual indica claramente que a pesar de que superes el límite diario los puntos por etiqueta se tendrían que seguir sumando.

También podía ser porque todavía no hubiera pasado el tiempo de actualización, pero de nuevo @Mariano me respondió con este otro link: [How are tag scores calculated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280818/how-are-tag-scores-calculated/280819#280819) en el cual indica que la actualización se procede a las `03:00 UTC`, por lo que ya se tendrían que haber actualizado.

Como ejemplo, podéis ver que en la etiqueta PHP tendría que tener 30 puntos y en cambio sigo teniendo 21. Esto lo podéis ver [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A16108%20%5Bphp%5D%20is%3Aanswer) y [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16108/error404?tab=tags).

¿Por qué no se actualizan los puntos por etiqueta? ¿Es algún tipo de bug?

**UPDATE:** Hoy se me han actualizado las puntos por etiqueta de PHP. Sin embargo, he observado que respecto al resto de etiquetas, los puntos de PHP se han actualizado los últimos. Por ejemplo, ayer conseguí algún punto de Java y se me actualizaron al momento siendo que las de PHP seguían marcando 21 puntos y que finalmente se han actualizado hoy.

Me resulta un poco raro que haya etiquetas que se actualicen antes que otras pero me iré fijando a ver si veo algún comportamiento similar en los próximos días.

**UPDATE 2:** Acabo de comprobar que los puntos por etiqueta no se refrescan de la misma manera y varía según la etiqueta.

Por ejemplo, acabo de ganar hace una hora 2 puntos de Java y ya los tengo actualizados. Sin embargo, los puntos de PHP que gané ayer, todavía no se han refrescado y me marca 35 en vez de 36.

Comment: Dudo mucho que los puntos de Java se te actualizaran al momento porque, tal y como comenté en mi respuesta, estos se calculan cada día a las 3 UTC, no en ningún otro momento.

Comment: @fedorqui Sí, lo sé, por eso me pareció un comportamiento extraño. De todas formas iré observando a ver si este comportamiento se sigue repitiendo.

Comment: @fedorqui Ahora puedes mirar en mi cuenta que los puntos de Java que me acaban de asignar hace una hora ya se han actualizado. Sin embargo, los puntos de PHP de ayer siguen sin refrescarse (supongo que hasta que vuelva a llegar el tiempo de refresco).

Comment: Cuento tus puntos de Java a través de respuestas y me salen 51 para 27 respuestas ahora mismo, que encaja con lo que tienes... es decir, tienes razón en que se actualizaron hace poco, no a las 3 UTC como creía. En cuanto a PHP, cuento [36 votos positivos a respuestas](http://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A16108+%5Bphp%5D+is%3Aa) ahora mismo pero la puntuación en tu perfil indica 35. Sí, esto es raro. Nótese por cierto que si pones el ratón sobre el número de la izquierda en la zona de _etiquetas_ allí te desglosa entre preguntas y respuestas.

Comment: La puntuación que aparece en la zona de etiquetas solamente corresponde a las respuestas. Nótese por tanto que no son 41 los que debes tener en php sino los obtenidos _solamente_ en respuestas ([sustrae estas](http://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A16108+is%3Aq+%5Bphp%5D), vaya)

Comment: @fedorqui Sí, realmente había puesto en mi pregunta 41 porque me había confundido y había contado tanto respuestas como preguntas pero en realidad antes sí que había comprobado que salía diferente puntuación juntando solamente las respuestas. Al menos no eran alucinaciones mías :D. Ya he corregido la pregunta.

Comment: Por tanto esto debería lanzar otra pregunta: ¿por qué se calculan a distintas horas?

Comment: @fedorqui Esta tarde pongo la pregunta ya que ahora no tengo mucho tiempo. O si no, te dejo todos los honores :)

Comment: Para futuros lectores: de acuerdo con lo visto en los comentarios de la otra pregunta que abriste, el asunto aquí es que en tu perfil usabas la opción "Siguiente medalla de etiqueta". Con ella, las puntuaciones se calculan cada vez que consultas tu perfil. De ahí este comportamiento.

Comment: @fedorqui Realmente aquí no era tanto ese tema si no el hecho de que habían pasado las 03:00 UTC y no se me habían actualizado los puntos por etiqueta al día siguiente. Por eso cree la otra pregunta, para especificar exactamente el otro comportamiento que observé.

Comment: Sí, la pregunta/respuesta fue sobre eso. Pero los comentarios de por aquí fueron entorno a esta confusión por saber por qué una etiqueta se actualizaba antes que otra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esto pasa con cierta frecuencia y se ha comentado en Meta Stack Exchange en distintas ocasiones.

- [Tag badges not being updated from Thu 19 to Fri 20?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212858/209901) (año 2013)
- [Tag info not updated regularly on profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217040/209901) (enero 2014)
- [Tag scores are not updated and the issue is getting worse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226681/209901) (marzo 2014)

En la segunda vemos una respuesta de uno de los desarrolladores de Stack Exchange:

> There are some database timeouts happening in the scheduled jobs that recalculate those scores starting on Jan 22 2014. This job is one of the most expensive things that are done on the site, we're trying to optimize it even further. I'll let you know when the fix will be pushed out.

Pero no hubo actualizaciones posteriores, por lo que parece que el tema sigue allí.

En la última de las preguntas que listo arriba podemos leer:

> Tag scores update is supposed to happen at 03:00 UTC every day. Tag scores are updated by a scheduled job that is time consuming and often times out  (see for example the answers for [Tag info not updated regularly on profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217040/tag-info-not-updated-regularly-on-profile/) and [Tag scores have not updated; script did not run](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178114/tag-scores-have-not-updated-script-did-not-run)).

Luego detalla cómo funcionó el script durante un mes particular:

> I've been writing down whether the scores were updated or not every
>   day in April.
>
> The results are:
>
> ```
> Day      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  
> Updated  -   -   -   ✓   -   ✓  -   -   -   -   -   ✓   -   -   - 
>
> Day      16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
> Updated  ✓   -   ✓   -   ✓   -   -   ✓  ✓   -   ✓  -   ✓   -   -
> ```

Resumiendo: el script es bastante "costoso", se ejecuta cada día a las 3:00 UTC y tiene síncopes frecuentes. Ningún desarrollador de Stack Exchange ha indicado si ha habido mejoras en él, por lo que podemos asumir que de vez en cuando no funcionará. Dado que funciona "al menos de vez en cuando" y no es una parte crítica, no creo que tenga excesiva prioridad en la lista de tareas.

Comment: Vale, esto estaba buscando. ¡Muchas gracias! Yo haré un update en cuanto se me actualicen las etiquetas.