# ¿Por qué algunos puntos de etiquetas se actualizan antes que otros?

Tags: discusión

Esta pregunta va en relación con esta otra: [¿Por qué no se añaden los puntos por etiqueta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1065/por-qu%C3%A9-no-se-a%C3%B1aden-los-puntos-por-etiqueta)

En la pregunta anterior tenía la duda de si había un bug respecto a que no se me habían actualizado los puntos por etiqueta (**los upvotes por etiqueta, no los +10**) aún habiendo pasado el supuesto refresco a las `03:00 UTC` pero me contestaron que no se refrescaba todos los días.

Hasta aquí todo bien, sin embargo, he detectado que hay puntos de etiqueta que se actualizan antes que otros. Es decir, dependiendo de la etiqueta se actualizan los puntos antes o después.

Por ejemplo, en mi caso, he detectado ya dos veces en los que los puntos de [java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) se han actualizado al momento mientras que los de [php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) han tardado más de un día en actualizarse (realmente estos últimos siguen sin haberse actualizado, con lo que supongo que si que siguen el patrón de la hora de refresco y de que no todos los días se refrescan los puntos por etiqueta).

Este comportamiento me parece bastante curioso, por lo que me ha surgido la siguiente duda: ¿hay etiquetas que tienen mayor preferencia a la hora de asignarse los puntos de las mismas que otras?

Comment: Pregunta, estas trackeando Java en la siguiente medalla de etiqueta? Al menos para mi, siempre veo que se actualiza voto por voto. Claro que debe tener mas de 100 preguntas la etiqueta para que funcione.

Comment: @rnd ¿Que significa "trackear"?

Comment: ooops .... sería "dar seguimiento" (discúlpame, fue españolizar una palabra de origen Ingles), me refiero a tu perfil, donde dice "Siguiente medalla de etiqueta"... la etiqueta seleccionada alli, se actualiza voto x voto.

Comment: @rnd Es decir, que si la tienes como "Siguiente medalla de etiqueta" es la primera que se actualiza, ¿no? Eso tendría más sentido y fue lo primero que pensé pero me parecía extraño de todas formas.

Comment: Claro, la cuenta de votos de la etiqueta que seleccionas para "Siguiente medalla de etiqueta" se actualiza cada vez que recibes un voto en esa etiqueta. El resto no, se actualizan en base diaria (como te explicaron ya, aveces el Job falla y no se actualizan). Ojo que no lo busque en Meta, lo se por verlo diariamente.

Comment: @rnd Vale, esa era la confirmación que quería. Puedes ponerlo como respuesta y así cerramos la pregunta. O, al menos, hasta que alguien diga lo contrario.

Comment: Ah claro, @rnd está en lo cierto. Veo alguna referencia a esto en [Tag score is shown incorrectly in the next badge tracker section](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326711/1983854). Básicamente, saber cuántos puntos llevas en una etiqueta es una funcionalidad asociada a la opción "siguiente medalla".